# Why is it wrong to pass a pointer to a function taking a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void print(char *str){
    cout<<str;
}

int main(){
    clrscr();
    char str[]="abcdef";
    print(&str);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Error**
1. Cannot convert 'char[7]' to 'char *'
2.Type mismatch in parameter 'str' in call to print(char *)

Since the parameter list of function print consists of a pointer, then passing **&str** in function call should be correct

Also if I remove the '&' the program runs fine (even though the print function requires a character reference).

Comment: What ancient compiler are you using?

Comment: [Back to the basics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You need a strong foundation for good results.

Comment: @CoryKramer `<iostream.h>` is a good indication it's Turbo C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Since the parameter list of function print consists of a pointer, then passing `&str` in function call should be correct

That's not exactly true: it is not sufficient to pass just any pointer, it needs to be of the correct type. `&str` is a pointer to an array, while you need a pointer to a single array *element*.

Since arrays in C++ "decay" to pointers when you pass them to functions, all you need to do is removing the ampersand:

```
print(str);
```

> if I remove the `&` the program runs fine (even though the print function requires a character reference)

That's right! An array name (in this case, `str`) is implicitly converted to a pointer, which is equal to the pointer to array's initial element. In other words, it's the same as writing

```
print(&str[0]);
```

Comment: Is pointer to an array not same as pointer to first element of array?

Comment: @abhishekgupta Numerically, a pointer to an array `&str` is often the same as the pointer to the initial element `&str[0]`. However, the compiler considers it a pointer of different type for the purposes of pointer arithmetic, so it disallows implicit conversion. The name of an array, however, can be converted to a pointer to array element implicitly, so in `char *p = str` the value of `p` matches `&str[0]` both numerically and by type.

Comment: Can you explain "the compiler considers it a pointer of different type for the purposes of pointer arithmetic, so it disallows implicit conversion ".

Comment: @abhishekgupta Adding `N` to a pointer `p` advances it by the `N*sizeof(*p)` numerically. For example, adding `1` to `&str` is not the same as adding `1` to `&str[0]`. Here is a quick [demo](http://ideone.com/4phvOW).

Answer (score 1):

```
print(&str);
```

is wrong since the type of `&str` is `char (*)[7]` while the expected argument type is `char*`.

To illustrate the difference between the two types:

```
char str[]="abcdef";
char (*ptr1)[7] = &str;   // Take the address of the array.
char* ptr2 = str;         // Use the array variable. It decays to a pointer

*ptr2 = 'A';        // OK.
*ptr1 = 'A';        // Not OK.

(*ptr1)[0] = 'A';   // OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `str` directly to `print()` like so:

```
// this already provides std::cout
#include<iostream.h>
// this is unnecessary
//#include<conio.h>

// you could do this to avoid std:: everywhere:
//using namespace std;

void print(char *str){
    // don't forget the namespace:
    std::cout<<str;
}
int main(){
    clrscr();
    char str [] = "abcdef";

    // no "&", just pass str
    print (str);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Arrays in C/C++ are just pointers to the first element of the array.

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/9/

Answer (score 0):

Function `print` is declared as having a parameter of type `char *`

```
void print(char *str){
    cout<<str;
}
```

Within the main it is called with an argument of type `char ( * )[7]` because it is this type that expression `&str` has.

```
char str[]="abcdef";
//...
print(&str);
```

You should call the function simply like

```
print( str );
```

In this case the array is converted to pointer to its first character and expression `str` has type `char *`

When you have an array of type `T` as for example

```
T a[10];
```

then the array used in expressions is converted to pointer to its first element. For example this

```
T *ptr = a;
```

is a correct declaration.

On the other hand if you are using expression `&a` then the correct declaration for a pointer will look like

```
T ( *ptr )[10] = &a;
```

That is in this case ptr is a pointer to an object of type `T[10]`

And I advice to use a more modern compiler.:)